# Delphi TDictionary with generics

Tags: dictionary, delphi, generics

I need a container with different TProc indexed by String.
Something like TDictionary.

```
TMessageBus = class
    private
        fContainer: TDictionary<String, TProc<T>>;  // ERROR !!
    public
        procedure Send<T>(aName: String; aData: T); // producer
        procedure Subscribe<T>(aName: String; aProc: TProc<T>); // consumer
end;
```

Please help.

Comment: Thank you, but this is other problem: list of TProc indexed by String

Comment: `System.Generics.Collections` has a generic dictionary

Comment: and this is a problem - how to get list TProc<T>  with different T ? To create a TDictionary, you must write types, like TDictionary.Create(String, TProc<Integer>) or TDictionary.Create(String, TProc<TObject>).

Comment: This is the old "it's turtles all the way down" problem. At some point you have to completely instantiate a generic type.

Comment: procedure Send<T>(aName: String; aData: T);
begin
    i = fContainer.IndexOf(aName);
    fContainer[i].Execute(aData)
end;
procedure Subscribe<T>(aName: String; aProc: TProc<T>);
begin
   fContainer.Add(aName, aProc);
end;

How to define fContainer ?

Comment: You aren't really embracing the issue. At some point, before you compile, you need to specify what `T` is. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that `TProc<T>` is implemented as interface you can write this code:

```
type
  TMessageBus = class
  private
    fContainer: TDictionary<string, IInterface>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Send<T>(const aName: string; const aData: T);
    procedure Subscribe<T>(const aName: string; const aProc: TProc<T>);
  end;

constructor TMessageBus.Create;
begin
  fContainer := TDictionary<string, IInterface>.Create;
end;

destructor TMessageBus.Destroy;
begin
  fContainer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMessageBus.Send<T>(const aName: string; const aData: T);
begin
  TProc<T>(fContainer[aName])(aData);
end;

procedure TMessageBus.Subscribe<T>(const aName: string; const aProc: TProc<T>);
begin
  fContainer.AddOrSetValue(aName, IInterface(PPointer(@aProc)^));
end;
```

However apart from leaving out any validation code this can easily blow up if you do send a different data type than you subscribed. So I would use the `TValue` type here to wrap the passed `TProc<T>` inside a `TProc<TValue>` (from `System.Rtti`). Keep in mind however that `TValue` itself only allows type conversions that also the compiler allows, so it won't convert `string` to `Integer` and alike - but if required you can then add this yourself:

```
type
  TMessageBus = class
  private
    fContainer: TDictionary<string, TProc<TValue>>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Send<T>(const aName: string; const aData: T);
    procedure Subscribe<T>(const aName: string; const aProc: TProc<T>);
  end;

constructor TMessageBus.Create;
begin
  fContainer := TDictionary<string, TProc<TValue>>.Create;
end;

destructor TMessageBus.Destroy;
begin
  fContainer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMessageBus.Send<T>(const aName: string; const aData: T);
var
  proc: TProc<TValue>;
begin
  if fContainer.TryGetValue(aName, proc) then
    proc(TValue.From<T>(aData));
end;

procedure TMessageBus.Subscribe<T>(const aName: string; const aProc: TProc<T>);
begin
  fContainer.AddOrSetValue(aName,
    procedure(aValue: TValue)
    begin
      aProc(aValue.AsType<T>);
    end);
end;
```

If you now call `mb.Send('somestring', 42);` for example it will raise an `EInvalidCast` exception in `TValue.AsType` because as mentioned before it can't convert the passed `42` to `string` which is what you specified when you called `Subscribe`.

Comment: Yes, this solution (with TValue) is great !! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a field dependent on the generic type T you have to make the complete class generic and not the methods:

```
type
  TMessageBus<T> = class
  private
    fContainer: TDictionary<String, TProc<T>>; // ERROR !!
  public
    procedure Send(aName: String; aData: T); // producer
    procedure Subscribe(aName: String; aProc: TProc<T>); // consumer
  end;
```

Comment: For procedures Send and Subscribe, sometimes T=Integer, or T=String and sometimes T=Object. Your code is correct, but not for this problem.

Comment: Then generics is the wrong solution. The thing about generics is that you have to decide at compile time what type to substitute for `T`. If you can't determine that at compile time, then generics won't help you.

Comment: @TomaszH This is (probably) the *only* solution involving generics.  In the end, how is calling FIntegerMessageBus.Send('',0) different from FMessageBus.Send<Integer>('', 0)?